# maximum number of independent bishops on a nxn chessboard

Tags: recreational-mathematics, contest-math, puzzle

So I came across this problem where we have to find the maximum number of independent bishops on a nxn chessboard such that no two bishops attack each other . So after drawing the cases for $3$x$3$ , $4$x$4$ and $5$x$5$ , it seems like that the pattern is $n$ on one side and $n-2$ on the other so the total number is $2n-2$ for a $n$x$n$ chessboard , but this is just a intuition , even if it is the right answer , I can't come with a justifiable logic.

What is the logic , actually ?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but aside from a few minor details we don't see from your work, if $2n-2$ is the solution you came to for $n=2,3,4...$, I'd think you did use justifiable logic.

Comment: 2n-2 is the correct answer, and the usual argument is a pigeonhole type argument.

Comment: What is the pigeonhole principle and how it is being used here?

Answer (score 3):

As @Michael says, you can count the diagonals in one direction, and note that you can't have both ends of a long diagonal, which then reduces the number by $1$

As for configurations, note that the bishops on black squares and those on white squares are completely independent of each other. So, for example, the black-squared bishops could be on the first and last row, and the white-squared bishops in the first and last column.

Comment: Can We Talk Sir, I have some doubt for this question and some things to ask in general ?

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of NE-SW diagonals, including both corners.